# Plugin to capture GIFs through camera for Codova

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, cordova-3, ngcordova

I am developing a mobile app that will need the user to capture a GIF using the mobile camera. I am using Cordova to develop the app using web technologies. Is there a plugin that will help me achieve what i am trying to do?

Comment: not sure but you can take video and convert it into .gif with https://github.com/louisondumont/phonegap-remoteVideo2gif plugin

Comment: @Naitik Yes i came to that solution as well. btw, thanks for taking the time to comment.